# Ajax to fill dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a webform that is used to collect and email details of a sporting match and send an email to the competition administrator.  I am working to improve the UI by using Ajax to call data from the database a pre fill the selects. I have successfully implemented Ajax to fill the home team names and one field of players name.

Where I am struggling is filling the away team names and other player name fields.

The list of competitions is called by a query on the webpage.  Once a competition is selected it fills the home team names via Ajax.  I need the same function to fill the away team names as well.

Once the home team is selected it fills the home team player names via Ajax for player one. There are however eight player entries for each team.

Any advice welcomed around reducing the Ajax calls to fill same data into multiple selects.

The select drop downs have a. I change trigger to activate the JS.

My JS calls are

```
<!-- Get Teams -->
<script>
     function getTeams(divisionId){
        $("#TeamsDropdown").html('<option>Loading...</option>');
        $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "getTeams.php",
           dataType: "html",
           data: {division: divisionId}
        })
           .done(function(data){
           $("#TeamsDropdown").html(data);
        });
     }  
  </script>

<!-- Get Players Home-->
<script>
     function getPlayersHome(clubId){
        $("#PlayersDropdown").html('<option>Loading...</option>');
        $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "getPlayers.php",
           dataType: "html",
           data: {TeamsDropdown: clubId}
        })
           .done(function(data){
           $("#PlayersDropdown").html(data);
        });
     }  
  </script>
```

getTeams.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['division'])){
require("config_db.php");
$comp_id = $_POST['division'];
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT
    fixs.hteam_id as id,
    team.tname,
    team.club_id
FROM 
fixtures fixs
    JOIN teams team on fixs.hteam_id = team.id
WHERE comp_id = :comp_id ORDER BY team.tname";
$teams = $db->prepare($sql);
$teams->execute(array(
  ':comp_id'   => $comp_id
));
echo "<option>Select Team...</option>";
foreach($teams as $team){
  echo "<option value='" . $team['club_id'] . "'>" . $team['tname'] . "</option>";
}}
```

getPlayers.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['TeamsDropdown'])){
require("config_db.php");
$club_id = $_POST['TeamsDropdown'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE club_id = :club_id AND active='Y' ORDER BY Surname";
$players = $db->prepare($sql);
$players->execute(array(
  ':club_id'   => $club_id
));
echo "<option>Select Player...</option>";
foreach($players as $player){
  echo "<option value='" . $player['id'] . "'>" . $player['Surname'] . "</option>";
}}
```

Example call

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="home">Home Team</label>
        <select name="home" id="TeamsDropdown" class="form-control" onChange="getPlayersHome(this.value)">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Code ???????????

Comment: What you can do is return JSON from php file with the teams and players after the ajax call and then parse it and fill dropdowns with javascript in your main file.

Comment: When do you call each Function?

Comment: The functions are called from the form selects when the required value is selected. Code added to original post.